# Splitting a Git repository based on arbitrary file paths

Tags: git, github

I have one git repository which I'd like to turn into two git repositories, however the split is not as simple as it seems `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` would like.

```
myRepo/
    a-main.js
    b-main.js
    a-other.js
    tests/
        a-tests.js
        b-tests.js
```

What I'd like to do is get another repository which only has the `a-*` files. *Note that I've just named them this way for clarity, the actual files don't have a common pattern. There is only a few, so it's no problem to list them individually.*

**What I've tried:**

```
git clone --no-hardlinks ~/myRepo ~/myRepoA
cd ~/myRepoA
git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm b-main.js tests/b-tests.js" \
                  --prune-empty HEAD
```

But this gives this output

```
Rewrite 4ce7... (1/46)rm: cannot remove `b-main.js': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `tests/b-tests.js': No such file or directory
tree filter failed: rm b-main.js tests/b-tests.js
```

**For bonus points:**

Once this is done, how do I push it to a new repository on Github?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was missing the `-f` flag:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f b-main.js tests/b-tests.js" \
                  --prune-empty HEAD
```

And for my own bonus points:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

Comment: A tip is to use --index-filter instead of --tree-filter, since the --index-filter operates on the index there's no need for git to checkout each commit e.g.:

git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -f --cached --ignore-unmatch b-main.js tests/b-tests.js" --prune-empty --tag-filter cat HEAD

I also added --tag-filter cat to rewrite tags